# bash + how to verify words are in list of values

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, variable

how to identify that all values in parameter - **var_general** are in **var_get**

for example

```
var_general="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"
var_get="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi"
```

according to this example will get status ok

other example

```
var_general="sdb sdj sdd sde sdf sdg"
var_get="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi"
```

we will get status fail ( because sdj not in var_get )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`bash`** + **`comm`** + **`tr`** solution:

```
var_general="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"
var_get="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi"

if [[ $(comm -23 <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var_general" | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var_get" | sort)) ]]; then 
    echo "status: Fail"
else 
    echo "status: Ok"
fi
```

---

- `tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var_general"` - translate spaces into newlines/linebreaks
- `comm -23 FILE1 FILE2` - compare files and print lines unique to `FILE1`. If the file `FILE1` doesn't contain differing items - then it is accepted as subset of file `FILE2`

Answer (score 1):

This function is working in my testing to accomplish this:

```
are_in () {
    local match_list="$1"
    local compare_list="$2"
    until [[ -z "$match_list" ]]; do
        if ( grep -q  "$(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$match_list")" <<<"$compare_list" ); then
            match_list="$(awk '{$1=""; print $0}' <<<"$match_list")"
        else
            echo "Fail" && return 1
        fi
    done
    echo "Okay" && return 0
}
```

Using:

```
$ var_general="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg"
$ var_get="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi"
$ are_in "$var_general" "$var_get"; echo $?
Okay
0
$ var_general="sdb sdj sdd sde sdf sdg"
$ var_get="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi"
$ are_in "$var_general" "$var_get"; echo $?
Fail
1
```

Without the function it is essentially just:

```
t_var="$var_general"
until [[ -z "$t_var" ]]; do
    if ( grep -q  "$(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$t_var")" <<<"$var_get" ); then
        t_var="$(awk '{$1=""; print $0}' <<<"$t_var")"
    else
        echo "Fail" && return 1
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk

```
awk -v b="ok" -v RS=' |\n' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){b="ko";exit}END{print b}' <(echo $var_get)  <(echo $var_general)
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and it will fail given various contents of the 2 shell variables due to missing quotes.

Comment: You are right for the missing quote. I try it with original-awk which came with debian and with awk on my OpenBSD 6.2 and it's OK.

Comment: No, it's not OK, your input must not be populated in a way that makes the problem visible. When any awk except gawk sees `RS=' |\n'`, that's undefined behavior per POSIX so best case it will quietly truncate that to `RS=' '`, discarding the `|\n` part, and so only use a single blank char as the RS so it'd fail if you did have `\n`s between records or multiple spaces between records.

Answer (score 0):

**`Python`** solution:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("status: {}".format("Ok" if set(sys.argv[1].split())
<= set(sys.argv[2].split()) else "Fail" ))' "$var_general" "$var_get"
```

---

- `sys.argv[1]` - the 1st argument passed to the *python* script (i.e. `"$var_general"`)
- `sys.argv[2]` - the 2nd argument passed to the *python* script (i.e. `"$var_get"`)
- `set<1> <= set<2>` - test if every element in `set<1>` is in `set<2>`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.issubset

Answer (score 0):

**Non-secure way** (because variables are not quoted)

```
comm -23 <(sort <(printf "%s\n" $var_general)) <(sort <(printf "%s\n" $var_get))
```

**More secure way**

```
comm -23 <(sort <(xargs -n1 <<< "$var_general")) <(sort <(xargs -n1 <<< "$var_get"))
```